# How to Get Next Auto Increment ID Before Inserting MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working on a C# standalone data entry application. This system is proposed to use by a centralized database(MYSQL 8.0) with many computers.
Data will enter using the wizard. Clicking next ->next and insert data only at the end of the wizard
Currently am getting the next ID by Client-side(c#)

```
SELECT MAX(id) + 1 AS ID
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

This method is ok for single-user applications. but when the database centralized and used by many computers it will crash IDs generated by this method.

Example - there are 3 (A, B) computers with installed the data entry system connected to a centralized database.
assume the last ID in TABLE is 5. Computer 'A' going to add data. Computer A will get the next ID as 6. Also, Computer 'B' starting to enter data at the same time. COmputer 'B' also get the next ID as 6.Then IDs will crash.

Can anyone suggest a solution to get the next id without the crash from the server-side? Please Provide an example.

Comment: can you not auto generate id on insert in  the DB?

Comment: you can easily get it after committing it, if this is okay I will show you how. or do you want to get it before you commit your data ?

Comment: Just Don't do this

Comment: @Mohammed I want to get it before committing because there are many tables that ID(s) require as foreign keys. if  your suggestion is better i can use it

Comment: If the ID is auto incremented and is the primary key, why go through all this trouble? The MyISAM storage engine supports concurrent inserts to reduce contention between readers and writers for a given table, unless you set the concurrent_insert system variable to NEVER (or 0)

Comment: `I want to get it before committing because there are many tables that ID(s) require as foreign keys.` Insert the record. Get the ID. Now insert the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you *do* try to get next ID (especially in a multi-client environment) it is not guaranteed to be the value by the time you perform the INSERT since one client could request and then another client request, both receiving the same response, and then one of the client performs the INSERT and ID matches what was returned while the other client's ID will not.

Thee 2 most basic approaches that you may want to evaluate in your given scenario are:

- Return the ID to the client after the INSERT is performed
- Change the ID from an auto-incremented ID to a GUID which can be generated by the client and passed into the database during the INSERT; this is a [common solution](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-uuid/) for distributed applications since the values are exceptionally unlikely not to be unique.